# Databind inside style="width: of div

Tags: asp.net, html, data-binding, databinder

I am facing a problem like this:
I have it in HTML page:

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width:80%;"></div>
```

BUT I'd like to use this 80% comming from a database.

so I'd tried this:

```
<div id="Percent" runat="server" class="bar bar-warning"  style='width: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number") %> %'>
```

But It didn't work. Can anyone help me to save my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove runat attribute from here if you want to set the inline width like below:

```
<div id="Percent" class="bar bar-warning"  style='width: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number") %> %'>
```

Otherwise you can set it from code behind:

```
<div id="Percent" runat="server" class="bar bar-warning" >

    Percent.Style.Add("width", "YourDatabaseValue");
```

Comment: No problem Matheus :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a server control, a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) is rendered as a div.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelSuccessBar" CssClass="bar bar-success" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

codebehind:

```
// number is a double value that is comeing from database
PanelSuccessBar.Width = new Unit(number, UnitType.Percentage);
```